# Close jQuery UI dialog on overlay click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

I want to close my modal when people click the overlay, normally u would use

```
jQuery('.ui-widget-overlay').bind('click', function() {
            jQuery('#dialog').dialog('close');
        })
```

but i am loading my modal after i create it, so it would seem that the above code interferes with mine somehow.
this is my code so far.

```js
var dialog = $(".dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        closeText: "",
        width: 'auto',
        modal: true,
        position: { my: "center top", at: "center top+30", of: "body" },
        show: {
            effect: 'fade',
            duration: 250,

        },
        hide: {
            effect: 'fade',
            duration: 250
        },
        
    });

    $(".currentDay").click(function () {
        var id = event.target.id;
        var url = '/Home/CalenderPartial/' + id;

        dialog.load(url, function () {
            dialog.dialog("open");

        });

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Check your jquery file, seems its not rendering on the page

Comment: the modal is working fine, it does 100% what its intended to do, the only thing im missing is the closing functionality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can bind the event inside the `open` method

```
var dialog = $(".dialog").dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  closeText: "",
  width: 'auto',
  modal: true,
  open: function(event, ui) {   //added here
    jQuery('.ui-widget-overlay').on('click', function() {
      jQuery('#dialog').dialog('close');
    });
  },
  position: {
    my: "center top",
    at: "center top+30",
    of: "body"
  },
  show: {
    effect: 'fade',
    duration: 250,

  },
  hide: {
    effect: 'fade',
    duration: 250
  },

});
```

Comment: yeah that is what i read on some other posts, but where would i put that?

Comment: sorry I didnt get when you say **where would I put that**

Comment: where in the above code would i put this open : function()? i have tried inputting it in several locations and it just breaks my modal.

Answer (score 0):

Okay i found the problem.
i was trying to close the dialog before it was initialized.

```js
    var dialog = $(".dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        closeText: "",
        width: 'auto',
        modal: true,
        position: { my: "center top", at: "center top+30", of: "body" },
        show: {
            effect: 'fade',
            duration: 250,

        },
        hide: {
            effect: 'fade',
            duration: 250
        },
        open: function () {
            jQuery('.ui-widget-overlay').on('click', function () {
                dialog.dialog('close');
            });
        },
    });

    $(".currentDay").click(function () {
        var id = event.target.id;
        var url = '/Home/CalenderPartial/' + id;

        dialog.load(url, function () {
            dialog.dialog("open");

        });

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

this is the code i ended up with, and this works as intended.

so to summarize, put this code inside your dialog init.

```
open: function() {
        jQuery('.ui-widget-overlay').on('click', function() {
            jQuery('#dialog').dialog('close');
        })
```